# file is not able to download in my express.js app

Tags: node.js, express

im trying to download pdf file which is saved in my public directory if node.js application. i have following route to download pdf file. but issue is that my file us not downloading from google chrome and also from postman. there is no any error in console. code is correct but file us not able to download. so please tell me whats the issue. i have following route.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
var path = require('path')

const app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
var CvRouter = express.Router();

    CvRouter.get('/', function(req, res,next){      
             var path=require('path');
             var file = "muhammadateek_cv.pdf";
             var path = path.resolve(".")+'/public/'+file;
             console.log('PATH=', path)
             res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=muhammadateek_cv.pdf');
             res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');  
             res.download(path);
                 next();
            })
app.use('/', CvRouter);
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000')
})
```

Comment: Check if the file path is valid and try `res.download(path)`

Comment: path is correct.. i console it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using next() callback in router after res.download function. problem was that whenever i request on '/' url my request go t next() without handled res.download(). when i remove next() callback my code is working fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the router.

Add below line before listening :

```
app.use('/', CvRouter);
```

**UPDATE**

You are using middleware like a route handler.

For using middleware you need to use like :

```
CvRouter.get(function(req, res,next){      

                 next();
            })
```

But you want to finish the request and send back a response (by downloading), so the right syntax for route handler is like :

```
CvRouter.get('/', function(req, res){      
             var path=require('path');
             var file = "muhammadateek_cv.pdf";
             var path = path.resolve(".")+'/public/'+file;
             console.log('PATH=', path)
             res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=muhammadateek_cv.pdf');
             res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');  
             res.download(path);
            })
```

Comment: your answer is correct no doubt. actual it was typo in my question code.

Comment: @MuhammadAteek You need to remove that next part. You use middleware like a route handler.

Comment: @MuhammadAteek My answer was wrong you take back your approve??